Regex to change dd day number to 01 after reading current date (Grafana-Influxdb)
I found the following regex that extracts the current date from the influxdb query
Query;
SHOW DIAGNOSTICS
Regex to extract date;
/([0-9]{4}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{2})/

This results in;
2024-05-07
I then want to change the day 07 (or any number) to 01. This way i have the current startday of the month, which i then can use in my stat panel in grafana (amount of kWh this and last month)
I read this post
link
Unfortunately I cannot fully comprehend the replace part, since it is for every string in the input
I'm really trying to find a clue but somehow cannot find what i'm looking for anywhere
part of it should be?;
Make 2 or 3 groups and use e.g. $2, i do that with brackets i think;
/([0-9]{4}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1})([0-9]{2})\

regex101 says;
2nd Capturing Group `([0-9]{2})`
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
{2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times 

After that I somehow need to replace, that's where i get stuck, i think i somehow need to use some of this code;
Ok, with binary numbers only it's easy, just replace 0?(1)+$ with 1 followed by a number of zeroes corresponding to the number of groups (containing 1) found by the regex
supposedly the regex that grafana uses is go-lang orientated, but i think (not sure) that PCRE comes close/is compatible
Is there anyone here that can lead me in the right direction or tell me how to do this?
It's in the text above

I'd suggest /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/ as regex and $1-01 as the substitute string. But how that can exactly be done in InfluxDB is unknown to me, but maybe this documentation can help?

It is a Lucene regex, not and far from PCRE.

@DouwedeHaan Thanks! I tried the following as query as variable; regexp.replaceAllString(r: /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, v: "$1", t: "$firstday") according to this link I'm using influxdb/ql 1.8 Any more tips?

@WiktorStribiżew Ok thanks, now I understand why ^ and $ didn't work

@Maikel looks like you want regexp.replaceAllString(r: /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, v: xxx, t: "$1-01") and replace xxx with the string that you are trying to replace into

@Nick Thanks! I need to find a way to put that into a Select statement but didn’t had time to figure that out. I let you know when I get it working

I could not figure it out do i edited the python script that writes to influxdb with the following lines;
# first day of month
input_dt = datetime.datetime.today()
res = input_dt.replace(day=1)
fdom = res.date()
fdom = fdom.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#print(fdom)
after that writing to influx in a new value
